# I don't have errors, but my app keeps closing

Tags: java, android, arrays, runtime-error

I have no Problem in based on the codes but why my app is keep closing when I run it
 I am a beginner in java 
I am making a quiz app for my thesis
 ps I only copy the codes in youtube and edit it 
Please help me to open my app

MainActivity.java

LtoQuiz.java

```
package com.example.ltoexam;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LtoQuiz extends AppCompatActivity {

    private com.example.ltoexam.QuestionLibrary nQuestionLibrary = new com.example.ltoexam.QuestionLibrary();

    private TextView nScoreView;
    private TextView nQuestionView;
    private Button nButtonChoice1;
    private Button nButtonChoice2;
    private Button nButtonChoice3;

    private String nAnswer;
    private int nScore = 0;
    private int nQuestionNumber = 0;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        nQuestionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        nButtonChoice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
        nButtonChoice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice2);
        nButtonChoice3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice3);

        updateQuestion();

        //Start of Button Listener for Button1
        nButtonChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //My logic for Button goes in here
                if (nButtonChoice1.getText() == nAnswer){
                    nScore =nScore + 1;
                    updateScore(nScore);
                    updateQuestion();
                    //This line of code is optional
                    Toast.makeText(LtoQuiz.this, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(LtoQuiz.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateQuestion();
                }
            }
        });

        //End of Button Listener for Button2


        //Start of Button Listener for Button2
        nButtonChoice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //My logic for Button goes in here
                if (nButtonChoice2.getText() == nAnswer){
                    nScore =nScore + 1;
                    updateScore(nScore);
                    updateQuestion();
                    //This line of code is optional
                    Toast.makeText(LtoQuiz.this, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(LtoQuiz.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateQuestion();
                }
            }
        });

        //End of Button Listener for Button2


        //Start of Button Listener for Button3
        nButtonChoice3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //My logic for Button goes in here
                if (nButtonChoice3.getText() == nAnswer){
                    nScore =nScore + 1;
                    updateScore(nScore);
                    updateQuestion();
                    //This line of code is optional
                    Toast.makeText(LtoQuiz.this, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(LtoQuiz.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateQuestion();
                }
            }
        });

        //End of Button Listener for Button2




    }
    private void updateQuestion(){
        nQuestionView.setText(nQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(nQuestionNumber));
        nButtonChoice1.setText(nQuestionLibrary.getChoice1(nQuestionNumber));
        nButtonChoice2.setText(nQuestionLibrary.getChoice2(nQuestionNumber));
        nButtonChoice3.setText(nQuestionLibrary.getChoice3(nQuestionNumber));

        nAnswer = nQuestionLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(nQuestionNumber);
        nQuestionNumber++;
    }


    private void updateScore(int point){
        nScoreView.setText("" + nScore);

    }

}
```

QuestionLibrary.java

```
package com.example.ltoexam;

public class QuestionLibrary {

    private String nQuestions [] = {
            "1.The three colors of the traffic lights are:",
            "2.Yellow triangular signs provide what kind of information",
            "3.Which of the following traffic signs are blue?",
            "4.Steady green light means",
            "5.A flashing yellow light at a road crossing signifies",
            "6.A solid white line on the right edge of the highway slopes in towards your left. This shows that",
            "7.You are in a No-Passing zone when the center of the road is marked by"

    };

    private String nChoices [] [] = {
            {"red, green and yellow", "red, green and blue", "yellow, green and blue"},
            {"warning", "hospital across", "speed limit"},
            {"regulatory signs", "information signs", "danger warning signs"},
            {"you must yield to all pedestrians and other motorists using the intersection", "go, it is safe to do so", "proceed cautiously through the intersection before the light changes to red."},
            {"Caution - slow down and proceed with caution", "Stop and stay until light stops flashing", "Wait for the green light"},
            {"there is an intersection joint ahead", "the road will get narrower", "you are approaching a construction area"},
            {"a broken yellow line","a broken white line","two solid yellow lines"}




    };

    private String nCorrectAnsers[] = {"red, green and yellow", "warning", "information signs", "go, it is safe to do so", "Caution - slow down and proceed with caution", "the road will get narrower", "two solid yellow lines"};

    public String getQuestion(int a) {
        String question = nQuestions[a];
        return question;
    }

    public String getChoice1(int a) {
        String choice0 = nChoices[a] [0];
        return choice0;
    }

    public String getChoice2(int a) {
        String choice1 = nChoices[a] [1];
        return choice1;
    }

    public String getChoice3(int a) {
        String choice2 = nChoices[a] [2];
        return choice2;
    }

    public String getCorrectAnswer(int a) {
        String answer = nCorrectAnsers[a];
        return answer;
    }


}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    tools:context=".LtoQuiz">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Score"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:id="@+id/score_text"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="0"
            android:id="@+id/score"/>




    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:text="Which thing is alive?"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/question"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="bird"
        android:background="#0091EA"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/choice1"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="door"
        android:background="#0091EA"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/choice2"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="rock "
        android:background="#0091EA"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/choice3"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Quit"
        android:background="#871C1C"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:id="@+id/quit"/>



</LinearLayout>
```

Myerror

```
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.ltoexam, PID: 4530
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ltoexam/com.example.ltoexam.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.ltoexam.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.ltoexam-M42DBs42t6LEwfwChdwEyw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.ltoexam-M42DBs42t6LEwfwChdwEyw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2793)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2979)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1683)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6754)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.ltoexam.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.ltoexam-M42DBs42t6LEwfwChdwEyw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.ltoexam-M42DBs42t6LEwfwChdwEyw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1180)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2783)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2979) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1683) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6754) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 4530 SIG: 9
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8614', transport: 'socket'
```

logcat not complete

08 18:54:20.316 595-595/? V/LocSvc_HIDL_IzatSubscription: [wifiSupplicantStatusUpdate][682] [HS] <<<<= [HC]
2020-03-08 18:54:20.316 1537-1911/? D/ConnectivityService: ignoring duplicate network state non-change
2020-03-08 18:54:20.331 1537-1911/? D/ConnectivityService: Update of LinkProperties for NetworkInfo [WIFI () - 151]; created=false; everConnected=false
2020-03-08 18:54:20.338 595-595/? V/LocSvc_HIDL_IzatSubscription: [wifiSupplicantStatusUpdate][682] [HS] <<<<= [HC]
2020-03-08 18:54:20.376 1537-3091/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) DhcpClient expire 54 lines
2020-03-08 18:54:20.377 1537-3093/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) Thread-279 expire 3 lines
2020-03-08 18:54:20.444 1537-2219/? D/DisplayPowerController: mSettingBrightness = -1 as request 233
2020-03-08 18:54:21.273 2895-2895/? I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 2895 SIG: 9
2020-03-08 18:54:21.306 1537-3661/? I/ActivityManager: Process com.bbk.theme.networkChange (pid 2895) has died: cch+2CEM 
2020-03-08 18:54:21.309 3437-3473/? E/VivoPush.AbeProcessObserver: (3437)remove pid error : pids is null
2020-03-08 18:54:21.309 1537-1972/? D/ScreenBrightnessModeRestore: pakage name is com.bbk.themewith :10051
2020-03-08 18:54:21.309 1537-1972/? D/ScreenBrightnessModeRestore:  onProcessDiedInner, pid = 2895 , mCurrent

Comment: Didn't find class "com.example.ltoexam.MainActivity"

Comment: Is your manifest written correctly? You should post that too

Comment: `"I have no errors"` but this `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ltoexam/com.example.ltoexam.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.ltoexam.MainActivity"` tells a different story.

Comment: Please post your manifest file (AndroidManifest.xml) code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello if you check this part of the error message:

```
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class"com.example.ltoexam.MainActivity"
```

You can see that, android studio is looking for that MainActivity class. And From a quick look over the information that you provide, there is no MainActivity class. This is the class that first gets called when you run your app, and has the layout of that activity_main. (it has to be called MainActivity.class)